# How to dynamically use the formula based on filter in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the total value without using the SUM function.

Example:

[image]

I can get the total value of SumSQ using SUM function like I did in the image.

Expected value is: 30323295

Formula of SumSQ: SumSQ = (SD^2 * count * (count - 1) + (SumX^2) ) / count

In excel: SumSQ =(SUMSQ(D3) * B3 * (B3-1)+(SUMSQ(C3)))/B3

Note that the SumSQ is kind of a helper column.

What I want is avoid using a helper column, in this case SumSQ. But I still want to get the total value which is 30323295.

So basically this is how it should look like without filter:

[image]

Formula for Total SumSQ: SumSQ = (total_SD^2 * total_count * (total_count - 1) + (total_SumX^2) ) / total_count

And note this must be dynamic based on filter on column A.

Example with filter in PC_Number:

[image]

It means that it should only compute what is only visible based on filter.

I have tried using SUBTOTAL() function added with OFFSET(), MIN(), and ROW() but it wont work as what I wanted to.

This is currently what I have:

```
--start

=SUMPRODUCT(((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(U5:U256,ROW(U5:U256)-MIN(ROW(U5:U256)),,1))^2)*SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(M5:M256,ROW(M5:M256)-MIN(ROW(M5:M256)),,1))*(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(M5:M256,ROW(M5:M256)-MIN(ROW(M5:M256)),,1))-1)+((SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(Q5:Q256,ROW(Q5:Q256)-MIN(ROW(Q5:Q256)),,1))*SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(M5:M256,ROW(M5:M256)-MIN(ROW(M5:M256)),,1)))^2))/SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(M5:M256,ROW(M5:M256)-MIN(ROW(M5:M256)),,1)))

--end
```

This is the output using the formula I have:

[image]

Which have a big difference on the total value.

Not sure I explained it well but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Added new update on the formula I have, I can now get the total value but I can't the value when filter is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal formula, not array formula, just using `SumProduct`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D3:D9*D3:D9*B3:B9*(B3:B9-1)+(C3:C9*C3:C9))/B3:B9)
```

OR

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D3:D9^2*B3:B9*(B3:B9-1)+(C3:C9^2))/B3:B9)
```

EDIT 1: filtering

To Add some filtering by `column A`, suppose you have to filter by a value that you enter in `A1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A9 = $A$1)*((D3:D9^2*B3:B9*(B3:B9-1)+(C3:C9^2))/B3:B9))
```

EDIT 2: to make the filtering optional, the next formula applies the filtering *unless* `A1` is blank, in which case it accounts for on all the rows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A9=IF(ISBLANK(A1),A3:A9,A1))*((D3:D9^2*B3:B9*(B3:B9-1)+(C3:C9^2))/B3:B9))
```

EDIT 3: to take into account only visible (non-filtered out) rows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(2, OFFSET(B1, ROW(B3:B9)-1,0))*((D3:D9^2*B3:B9*(B3:B9-1)+C3:C9^2)/B3:B9))
```

Idea is that the `subtotal(2)` on an individual and numeric cell returns 1 (0) if the cell is visible (hidden).

Comment: +1, better answer than mine for sure. Damn `SUMPRODUCT()` always slips under my radar. Both work, this is just better, and faster with more data.

Comment: @Kyle yes both work, +1 for yours too. We were working on it together. SumProduct is magic bc it deals with arrays internally but doesn't require an array formula. It took me time to get used to it too, but it is really magic.

Comment: @Kyle I think we still have an issue to solve... We still need to deal with the filtering on column A!

Comment: Good point, although that should really be ancillary. Would be best to set this up so that it isn't dependent on visible/non-visible cells, because I don't believe there is a non VBA way to do that. Hopefully someone proves me wrong.

Comment: @Kyle I agree with you, that's why I added some "explicit" filtering inside the formula.

Comment: Very nice! That will only filter on 1 value though, correct?

Comment: @Kyle yep. It can be taken further, but awaiting the OP's comments to see how far it should go :)

Comment: Sorry, but added new details and screenshot for more details, I think I missed out some info regarding the filtering...

Comment: @A.S.H I kind of get the total value using the formula I have (see updated post), changes is that I did not use SUMSQ(), instead SUMPRODUCT(). However, it still won't work when filter is applied.

Comment: @quinekxi well, means you want the filtering to apply based on visibility. I hope the `EDIT 3` achieves that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an array formula, and I don't believe you can use `SUMSQ()`. The below prodcues the desired result. Please not this is to be entered with `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`.

```
{=SUM(((D3:D9)^2 * (B3:B9)*((B3:B9)-1)+((C3:C9)^2))/B3:B9)}
```